# Angular styles not applying when insert component inside shadow-root

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass, shadow-dom

In my app, I use the widget which displays in shadow-root, and inside it has a div with an id where I need to insert my component. Like:

```
<widget>
  #shadow-root (open)
    ....
    <div id='container'> // need to insert component here // </div>
    ...
</widget>
```

For now, in `test.html` I have simple

```
<div #test>It works!</div>
```

In widget settings, I could get this `<div id='container'></div>` as parameter and pass it to my component, so `test.ts` looks like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.less'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Test implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() container: HTMLDivElement,
  @ViewChild('test', { static: true }) test: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const testElement = this.test.nativeElement;
    container.appendChild(testElement);
  }
}
```

The problem is that when it inserts to the shadow-root it doesn't see the styles from `test.component.less`. I tried `:host{}` `:host ::ng-deep {}` and it still doesn't work.

So my question is - is there a way to apply styles from `test.component.less` to my .html file, while it's inside shadow-root?

Would be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need set view encapsulation to none

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.less'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

hope helped you.

Comment: Oh sorry, hope anyone can help :)